# Show that there do not exist nonsingular matrices $P,Q ∈ M_{n×n}(F )$ satisfying $PAQ = A^T$ for all $A ∈M_{n×n}(F )$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $F$ be a field and let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that there do not
>   exist nonsingular matrices $P,Q ∈ M_{n×n}(F )$ satisfying $PAQ = A^T$ for all
>   $A ∈M_{n×n}(F)$. (Exercise 438 from Golan, *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*.)

If I set $A=I$, the identity matrix, then $P=Q^{-1}$ and If I set $A=Q$ then $Q=Q^T$, and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: this is for $n \geq 2$? If not, I'm not reading it correctly.

Comment: yes, $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Have you tried to see what the implications are when $A=E_{ij}$, the matrix with a 1 at the $(i,j)$-th entry and zero elsewhere? Exercises like this can usually be solved with this approach.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think I would take a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessarily $P=Q^{-1}$ and $P$ is symmetric invertible. Then, for every $A\in M_n(F)$, $PA=A^TP$, that is, $PA\in S_n(F)$, the space of symmetric matrices. Let $f:A\in M_n(F)\rightarrow PA\in M_n(F)$; since $f$ is a linear isomorphism, $dim(S_n(F))=n(n+1)/2\geq dim(M_n(F))=n^2$, that is false when $n\geq 2$.

Comment: it is not enought to say $\mathscr{M}_{n\times n}(F)\cong S_{n\times n}(F)$ which implies $\mathscr{M}_{n\times n}(F)=S_{n\times n}(F)$ and that is not true since there are not simmetrical matrices?

Comment: Yes. One obtains $M_n(F)= S_n(F)$; we can say that, if $n\geq 2$, there are matrices that are not symmetric.